# How to setup a layout on top and bottom Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create this layout above but I can't get it.
All these blocks, are images. The first two lines is a GridView that I fill on the OnCreate using an adapter. That´s ok, it shows aligned on top of the screen.
My problem is with the 5 images that should be aligned on bottom of the screen.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/img_fundo_pp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView android:id="@+id/grid1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="90dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <View android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top">
            <Space android:layout_width="10dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_link_site"/>
            <Space android:layout_width="10dp" />
            <Space android:layout_width="10dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_link_facebook"/>
            <Space android:layout_width="10dp" />
            <Space android:layout_width="10dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_link_htmj_pp"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Space android:layout_width="10dp" />
            </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: desired layout]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your layout with this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/spacer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your root layout Relative layout and whatever yo want to setup in bottom add all in one layhout and give below property. That's it.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```